# Проблема с редиректом порта на 433

Tags: веб-сервер, tomcat, ssl, https

Перепробовал большое количество вариантов с разными конфигурациями server.xml и результат плачевный. При подключении на `https://my.domain:433/MyWebApp/` все работает и соединение проверено (сертификат LetsEncrypt). При подключении на `http://my.domain/MyWebApp/` успешно происходит переход на https и на этом все. Браузер выдает ошибку ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Уже даже не знаю что делать ведь в логах catalina, localhost и localhost_access_log ничего нет кроме записей об успешном запуске (и чьих-то попыток перебора базовых страниц php). Заранее спасибо за хоть какую-то помощь. Готов дополнить вопрос всей необходимой информацией.
Сервер tomcat9 стоит на Ubuntu 18

server.xml:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           redirectPort="443"/>

<Connector
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        port="433" maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576"
        secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" scheem="https"
        keystoreFile="key_file.ks" keystorePass="myPassword" keyAlias="myKey"
        clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Окончание web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Simplex</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Сам мучался с редиректами, потом поставил nginx и выпилил все ssl и https из Java. Проблем больше не знаю....

Comment: А ничо что это зарезервированный порт который имеет свои требования?

Comment: Какая ОС хостит все это?

Comment: @Alexey R. исправил вопрос

Comment: Я поддерживаю @VladVetrov. Не мучайтесь с настройкой томката. Поставьте nginx, настройте в нём reverse proxy, добавьте ваш сертификат и задайте редирект с http на https. Всё будет работать. Проверено неоднократно.